# How to make div to overlay parent div

Tags: html, css

Pink and green layout are parent layout. When gray layout is clicked blue layout will be created. I want blue layout overlay the parent layout (pink and green) and comes to top.

But the blue layout is overlay by pink layout. I need help on it.

```css
div{
    display:block;
}
#content{
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:green;     
}
.center{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#808080;         
    text-align: center;
    margin:auto;
}      
#foo{
    background-color:#2060ff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">    
    <div id="d" class="center">    
        <div class="center">
            Click here to create new blue element
        </div>      
    </div>       
    <div style="background-color:pink;width:100%;height:20px;"></div>  
</div>
```

Check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edisonthk/wbfTq/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some positioning and a z-index...

```
#foo{
    position: relative;
    background-color:#2060ff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wbfTq/5/)**

Answer (score 2):

You need to adjust the [**z-index**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp). z-index needs to be positioned to work correctly. See [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wbfTq/2/).

```
#foo{
    background-color:#2060ff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: Why punch the user in the face with such a high `z-index`? 1 will work just fine.

Comment: you are correct 1 works fine. If you ever need to work with multiple layers it is nice to give yourself some room to place something below it without adjusting each z-index. Granted 100 is maybe excessive if this is the only layering that will happen.

Comment: Yeah, I agree -- just wanted to point it out for future reference. I like to use the very lowest possible because I feel it makes maintainability easier in the future.

Comment: It seems if you use the very lowest then that leaves you no margin to add layers below it without changing the value for every element that is on top, that seems less maintainable to me.

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest absolute positioning?

```
#foo{
    position:absolute; // <-- here is the change
    background-color:#2060ff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

This, of course, is if I understand your question correctly...

Comment: Sorry for I am not making my question clear enough. I want blue layout able to append it

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is to use a z-index. According to http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp specifies the stack order of an element. Please note you will have to make the div's relative Please see code

http://jsfiddle.net/wbfTq/16/

```
    div{
    display:block;
}
#content{
    position: relative;
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:green;     
}
.center{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#808080;           
    text-align: center;
    margin:auto;
}      
#foo{
    position: relative;
    background-color:#2060ff;
    z-index:1px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

Do let me know if this answers your question!

Comment: `z-index` has to be a number, cannot be in pixels